# I'm trying to create a simple loop but I'm stuck on line 18 it seems

Tags: python, loops

```
secret_number = 777

print(
"""
+================================+
| Welcome to my game, muggle!    |
| Enter an integer number        |
| and guess what number I've     |
| picked for you.                |
| So, what is the secret number? |
+================================+
""")

    guess_number = int(input("What is the secret number?"))
#if number is not equal to 777 continue
    while guess_number != secret_number:
    
    If guess_number == secret_number:
        guess_number = secret_number
    #Input the next number
    guess_number = int(input("What is the secret number?"))

print("Ha ha! You're stuck in my loop!")
print("Well done, muggle! You are free now.")
```

Comment: On line 18 you have an `If`, which should be `if`. Python is case-sensitive. You should be using an IDE to write your code so that it will inform you of such mistakes right away, and explain them. Also, for some reason lines 14 is indented, seemingly for no reason, which will also cause an error, because indentation is a critical structural component of Python code.

Comment: Is this your actual indentation? I would suspect, at a minimum, that your `if` should be indented to be inside the loop? Python uses indentation to determine what is "inside" a `while` or `if` or other code blocks that are started with a `:`.

Comment: `If guess_number == secret_number:  guess_number = secret_number` doesn't make any sense, since they are already equal

Comment: @Random Davis Most of the indentation comes from trying to satisfy stack overflow's need to format code properly.

Comment: @JNevill Most of the indentation comes from trying to satisfy stack overflow's need to format code properly.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki I agree, I think when I tried 777 the number it gave me an error.

Comment: @JJaxxon understood. If you copy/paste your code into the editor with the indentation in place, then highlight the pasted code and click the `{}` button in the editor it will indent the code with 4 spaces and all of the whitespace will be preserved. It's a bit tricky the first time.

Comment: @JJaxxon I get that you're new but you can't blame the site for your mistake. We just want you to fix it, not explain why you made that mistake. And, all you have to do is add 3 backticks (\`\`\`) to the top and bottom of your code, there's no need to indent it in the first place.

Comment: @JNevill Thank you for that tip,I will keep that in mind!!

Comment: @RandomDavis Sometimes explaining how and why I made the mistake may help for the sake of communication but I understand your response. Thank you for that.

Answer (score 0):

You have several syntax errors, the one you are seeing now is incorrect indentation. You need to start at the begining on the line.

Solved:

```
secret_number = 777

print(
"""
+================================+
| Welcome to my game, muggle!    |
| Enter an integer number        |
| and guess what number I've     |
| picked for you.                |
| So, what is the secret number? |
+================================+
""")

guess_number = int(input("What is the secret number?"))
#if number is not equal to 777 continue
while guess_number != secret_number:

    #if guess_number == secret_number:
        # guess_number = secret_number
        # note that the previous line is unnecessary
    #Input the next number
    guess_number = int(input("What is the secret number?"))

    print("Ha ha! You're stuck in my loop!")
    #this should be at the top, otherwise it will be printed even 
    #if you guess correctly the first time
print("Well done, muggle! You are free now.")
```

Comment: well, althoud this solves the syntax and indentation the code still doesn;t make sense

Comment: He is clearly a beginner, don't be too harsh.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki The first answer helps me better, thank you for that. I've got my code and your code side by side and I'm analyzing to see where I went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

apart from the `If` which should be `if` and the indentation problems, your code has parts that are not needed.

You don't need to check if they are equal inside the loop, since you are already checking that in the while condition.

Try something like this:

```
secret_number = 777

print(
"""
+================================+
| Welcome to my game, muggle!    |
| Enter an integer number        |
| and guess what number I've     |
| picked for you.                |
| So, what is the secret number? |
+================================+
""")

# guess the number for the first time
guess_number = int(input("What is the secret number?"))

#if number is not equal to 777 enter the loop
while guess_number != secret_number:
    print("Ha ha! You're stuck in my loop!")
    # Input the next number
    guess_number = int(input("What is the secret number?"))

print("Well done, muggle! You are free now.")
```